# Provisioning profile does not upload in Xcode (no error)

Tags: ios, xcode

I currently am in Xcode with a device selected under the window "Provisioning profiles installed on iphone" [image]

I attempt to upload a provisioning profile I download from the app developer portal on Apple.

[image]

The image shows the file which is selectable.  When I click "Install" nothing happens.  It doesn't give me an error and just goes back to "Provisioning profiles installed..."
Am I supposed to add an extension to the file or do something else?

Comment: Just wondering: is the profile still valid (i.e. not expired)?

Comment: I just created it @VadimBelyaev

Comment: Have you tried setting this profile in the code signing settings of your target and then just running the app on the device (unless your case is more complicated than this)? The profile should get installed by doing that.